# TQFT and Principle G-Bundles

Tags: mathematical-physics, principal-bundles, cobordism

I'm reading [this](http://www.math.harvard.edu/theses/senior/lee/lee.pdf) paper.  On page 27 near the middle the author writes

> Since $\pi_1(B)$ for the pair of pants $B$ is the free group on two
>   generators $\mathbb{Z}*\mathbb{Z}$, a principal $G$-bundle $\zeta$ is
>   the same as a conjugacy class of a pair $(g,h)\in G\times G$.

I know why $\pi_1(B)$ is $\mathbb{Z}*\mathbb{Z}$ but why does that mean that  a principal $G$-bundle $\zeta$ is the same as a conjugacy class of a pair $(g,h)\in G\times G$?

Comment: PrincipAL. ${}{}$

Comment: You are missing the keyword "principal *flat* bundle". Isomorphism classes of such bundles are parameterized by conjugacy classes of representations $\pi_1(B)\to G$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The classification of bundles on a space depends only on the homotopy type of the space, you can replace the surface by a wedge of two circles. Now a bundle over such a wedge is constructed in an obvious way from two bundles over the circle. That leaves you with the problem of classifying bundles over a circle. That can be done using the clutching construction, for example.